# $(data).find("some tag") not works

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

have this code:

```
$.post("auth.php", {pass : pass}, function(data) {
        var x = $(data).find("span#c");
        $("div#addform").show();
        menu.html(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(x);
        alert(x);
```

and php:

```
if($ath['mail'] != $pass){ echo "<center> try another pass )</center>";} else {
    // print all db
    echo("<span id=\"c\">OK</span><br>");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

in response gets text/html but in console i get just "[]" and [object Object] if do alert(x) all data loads perfect in menu.html(data); but why i can't get my 'x' span
what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show us what's held in `data`?

Comment: <div class="result">user: 1 id: some id email: 12345<br></div>

Comment: <div class="result">user: 2 id: some id2 email: 12345<br></div>

Comment: there's your problem. You're looking for `<span id="c">`, but it doesn't exist in `data`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find`.

`find` searches children of the jQuery element, but in your code, data *is* the `<span>`.  It doesn't have any children.

Answer (score 0):

`.find` is to find the children; the `span` is not a child.

Answer (score 0):

try like this http://jsfiddle.net/qW4nB/

Comment: `$(data)` will change it into a jQuery object.

Comment: sorry. yes we can use filter for that. i check and updated using filter